# how to put a variable in #ed section in shell

Tags: shell, sh

I have this script to run a simulation on cluster. As far as I know my cluster accepts only shell scripts. I want to put variable LAMBDA next to  the #PBS -N, but my variable gets commented out and I can't do anything about it. I can't remove the "#" because I feel it's a predefined setting to run on cluster.Is there any way I can achieve that ? please understand it's not a comment #PBS -N is a way of giving the name to the simulation.It's unintentionally getting commented out.

```
LAMBDA= 0.05 

 #PBS -N $LAMBDA_0.05_m_1_200k
 #PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1,pmem=1000mb
 #PBS -S /bin/bash
 #$ -m n
 #$ -j oe


 FOLDER= 0.57

 WDIR=/home/vikas/ala_1_free_energy/membrane_200k/restraint_decoupling_pullinit_$FOLDER

 cd /home/vikas/ala_1_free_energy/membrane_200k/restraint_decoupling_pullinit_$FOLDER


 /home/durba/gmx455/bin/mdrun -np 1 -deffnm md0.05 -v
```

Comment: The commented lines in the script are just .. comments. Expanding your variable onto a commented line does nothing. That is indeed the nature of comments -- they do nothing. From what I see of your script, it has five lines that do anything -- three lines set environment variables, one changes to a new directory, and the last line runs another command. If the commented lines have some other function, please edit your question and provide more details. [What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)?

Comment: ok, i will edit my question.

Comment: So many questions. There certainly doesn't seem to be enough information here to provide an authoritative answer.  If this is a shell script, is there something pre-processing it and commenting out those lines? What shell are you using? (There is no "shebang" in the example in your question.) Don't know if this is relevant, but how is the shell script distributed to cluster nodes and/or what cluster management system are you using?  Is the clip in your question the script that YOU PROVIDE, or the one that gets copied to the nodes after pre-processing?

Answer (score 0):

What for? You could echo the comments and see the 'comment' & variable that way as a workaround.

Comment: sorry to not explaining nicely ,actually it's not a comment, PBS sets the name of the simulations, which can't be echoed,It should remain  as it is. Thought I might want to try your suggestion

Comment: No problem, would it be possible to write a new file using the shell script? That way you could write a new script from the original script with the variable set.